# Timing Kernel Executions on CUDA

Tags: c, parallel-processing, gpu, cuda

I've used code from CUDA C Best Practices to implement an execution timer. However their is something strange and I don't know if it's an anomaly or if that's normal. I get different read outs each time I run my CUDA app.

Could these readings by related to design or is that something I should expect.

I'm not running any graphic intensive applications on my machine, other than Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends how big the differences are. One thing you can see anomalies caused by is the kernel scheduler. It may just happen that the scheduler is giving some extra timeslices to kernel functions (because graphics API calls have error checking involved) which shows more execution time. If the differences are very large I would say check your code but if it's very low in orders of milliseconds I wouldn't worry about it +- 10msecs is the usual for the timeslicing quantum in most OS's (windows probably included).
Also Aero is kind of intensive so that may be adding to the discrepancies you are seeing.

Comment: Sometimes it's a few milliseconds sometimes it's in a several tens of milliseconds. :S

Comment: I would say that's acceptable in windows I've seen discrepancies of up to about 500ms sometimes for no obvious reasons so I'm not sure what's happening in the background but it would be within normal bounds for me. Again I wouldn't trust the odd ones out that are a couple milliseconds off or so.

Comment: Have you ran the similar sample on other platforms without the same anomaly popping up?

Comment: I would expect it to still pop up on other platforms albeit not as much due to timeslicing quantums on different OS's

Comment: You wouldn't worry about -/+ 10 msec? That's a lot of time, man! :-(

Answer (score 0):

> I've used code from CUDA C Best Practices to implement an execution timer.

Yeah, well, that's not a "best practice" in my experience.

I suggest using the [`nvprof`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/) profiler instead for your device-side code and CUDA Runtime API calls (it also works relatively well, I think, for your own host-side code). It'll take you a bit of hassle to set up and figure out which options you want to use, but it's worth it.